# Find a bijection map

Tags: functions

I am trying to construct a bijection mapping for two sets but cannot make much progress, can someone take a look and offer some help?

A is the set of subsets of {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, each with 3 elements, and B is the set of subsets
of {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, each with 2 elements. The goal is to find a bijective function for these two sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just map any set in the first collection to its complement.

Comment: smart! thanks a lot!